# How to animate same on five different images but one at a time. When one is animated other should come in its original position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have six vertical dots in form of image i want to animate them using jquery but one at a time .. when i click another image(dot) the active image(dot) animation should come to its original position and the click image(dot) should animate

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".paralx-dot-1").click(function(){
    $(this).animate({
      height: '60.18px',
      width: '60.26px',
     
    
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.paralx-dot-1{
height:24.75px;
width:24.75px;
cursor:pointer;
display:inline-block;
outline:none;
}
```

```html
               <div class="col-md-12 icon-div-position" id="imgWrap">
                 <ul class="paralx-position">
                   <li class="paralx-dots"><span class="icon-text">Accelerate</span><img src="images/Circle 1- Blue .svg" class="paralx-dot-1" data-box="div2" id="img2" tabindex="0"></img></li>
                   <li class="paralx-dots"><span class="icon-text">Transform</span><image src="images/Circle 1- Blue .svg" class="paralx-dot-1" data-box="div3" id="img3" tabindex="0"></image></li>
                   <li class="paralx-dots"><span class="icon-text-main">Build</span><image src="images/Circle 1- Blue .svg" class="paralx-dot-2" class="Active" data-box="div1"  id="img1"  tabindex="0"><span class="icon-position"><image src="images/logos/noun_build_1909132.svg" class="icon"></image></span></image></li>
                   <li class="paralx-dots"><span class="icon-text">Ignite</span><image src="images/Circle 1- Blue .svg" class="paralx-dot-1" data-box="div4" id="img4"  tabindex="0"></image></li>
                   <li class="paralx-dots"><span class="icon-text">Develop</span><image src="images/Circle 1- Blue .svg" class="paralx-dot-1" data-box="div5" id="img5" tabindex="0"></image></li>
                   <li class="paralx-dots"><span class="icon-text">Engineer</span><image src="images/Circle 1- Blue .svg" class="paralx-dot-1" data-box="div6" id="img6" tabindex="0"></image></li>
                 </ul>
               </div>
```

Right now all are animating i want one at a time when only clicked and previously clicked animation reset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get the height and width of your `original image`. When you click on specific `image` set height and width of all other images with the original height, width.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    const height = $('.paralx-dot-1')[0].height;
    const width = $('.paralx-dot-1')[0].width;
    $(".paralx-dot-1").click(function(){
      $('.paralx-dot-1').css({"height": height, "width": width});
      $(this).animate({
        height: '60.18px',
        width: '60.26px',
      });
    });
});
```

```css
.paralx-dot-1{
    height:24.75px;
    width:24.75px;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:inline-block;
    outline:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12 icon-div-position" id="imgWrap">
  <ul class="paralx-position">
      <li class="paralx-dots"><span class="icon-text">Accelerate</span><img src="images/Circle 1- Blue .svg" class="paralx-dot-1" data-box="div2" id="img2" tabindex="0"></img></li>
      <li class="paralx-dots"><span class="icon-text">Transform</span><image src="images/Circle 1- Blue .svg" class="paralx-dot-1" data-box="div3" id="img3" tabindex="0"></image></li>
      <li class="paralx-dots"><span class="icon-text-main">Build</span><image src="images/Circle 1- Blue .svg" class="paralx-dot-2" class="Active" data-box="div1"  id="img1"  tabindex="0"><span class="icon-position"><image src="images/logos/noun_build_1909132.svg" class="icon"></image></span></image></li>
      <li class="paralx-dots"><span class="icon-text">Ignite</span><image src="images/Circle 1- Blue .svg" class="paralx-dot-1" data-box="div4" id="img4"  tabindex="0"></image></li>
      <li class="paralx-dots"><span class="icon-text">Develop</span><image src="images/Circle 1- Blue .svg" class="paralx-dot-1" data-box="div5" id="img5" tabindex="0"></image></li>
      <li class="paralx-dots"><span class="icon-text">Engineer</span><image src="images/Circle 1- Blue .svg" class="paralx-dot-1" data-box="div6" id="img6" tabindex="0"></image></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

add a new class named `animate`:

```
.animate {
      height: 60.18px;
      width: 60.26px;
      transition: 0.3s;
      -o-transition: 0.3s;
      -moz-transition: 0.3s;
      -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
}
```

and in javascript:

```
$(".paralx-dots").on("click", function(){
    $(this).siblings().removeClass("animate");
    $(this).addClass("animate");
  });
```